# Complexity for edge addition (planar graph)?

Tags: complexity-theory, graph-theory

I created a program that adds edges between vertices. The goal is to add as many edges as possible without crossing them(ie Planar graph). What is the complexity?

Attempt: Since I used depth first search I think it is O(n+m) where n is node and m is edge.

Also, if we plot the number of edges as a function of n what is it going to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is impossible to answer, since you have not described the algorithm.

For your second question, any maximal planar graph with v ≥ 3 vertices has exactly 3v - 6 edges.